# how to pass props into component from route array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I am define route `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.1",`  like this:

```
const Channel = loadable(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'about' */ '@/views/App/Cruise/Channel'))


const routes = [
    { path: '/index', exact: true, name: 'Index', component: Channel, auth: [1] }
]
```

for the old way, I am pass props into component like this way:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <Login user={this.props.user} />}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>)
    }
}
```

how to pass props into component Channel when define route as an array? I have tried this way:

```
{ 
        path: '/app/cruise/channel', 
        exact: false, 
        name: 'Channel', 
        render: (props) => (<Channel {...props} channel={this.props.channel}/>)
    },
```

but it could not work. Now I am passed the props like this in the routes outer component:

```
<Content className='content'>
                        <Switch>
                            {routes.map(item => {
                                return (
                                    <Route
                                        key={item.path}
                                        path={item.path}
                                        exact={item.exact}
                                        render={props =>
                                            !auth ? (
                                                <item.component {...props} channel = {this.props.channel}/>
                                            ) : item.auth && item.auth.indexOf(auth) !== -1 ? (
                                                <item.component {...props} channel = {this.props.channel} />
                                            ) : (
                                                <Redirect to='/404' {...props} />
                                            )
                                        }></Route>
                                )
                            })}
                            <Redirect to='/404' />
                        </Switch>
                    </Content>
```

it could work but I think it is a very ugly way, any better suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to access URL params or pass custom params?

Comment: I want to pass data through props @TJ

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would use the Link component to route to the correct location. So you could use routes and Link as below

```
 const Channel = loadable(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'about' */ '@/views/App/Cruise/Channel'))


const routes = [
    { path: '/index', exact: true, name: 'Index', component: Channel, auth: [1] }
]
```

Link in APP

```
const App=(props)=>{

return (
<Link to={{
              pathname:'/index',
              user:props.user
            }} >Channel
</Link>
)

}
```

Inside channel you can access user from props.location.user